# Error in effect() function in effects package

Tags: r

When I try to use `effects::effect`, it throws the following error:

```
Error in Effect.lm(predictors, mod, vcov. = vcov., ...) : 
  could not find function "vcov."
```

This error can be reproduced with this code:

```
lm_mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

library(effects)
effect("wt", lm_mtcars, list(wt = seq(2, 3, 0.1)))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you have "wt" as focal predictor then you need to call Effect (capital e): Effect("wt", lm_mtcars, list(wt = seq(2, 3, 0.1)))

Comment: The error arises because you did not name the `xlevels` argument. Older versions of effects::effect might have had a different third argument that could be positionally matched but the current version does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error arises because you did not name the `xlevels` argument. Older versions of `effects::effect` might have had a different third argument that could be positionally matched but the current version does not.

This will probably deliver what you were expecting:

```
lm_mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

library(effects)
effect("wt", lm_mtcars, xlevels=list(wt = seq(2, 3, 0.1)))
```